# Dependency Property "cascade" binding

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, dependency-properties

I'm rather new to WPF/XAML and I've encountered a problem which I'm not sure how to get around.

I'm going to describe my problem using an example. I need to develop an app, which will display tennis courts together with player photos and names on these courts. I created two user controls: `TennisCourt` and `TennisPlayer`. The `TennisCourt` control contains 4 instances of `TennisPlayer` control.

`TennisPlayer` has a DP of type `Player`, which contains the player's name and photo.

`TennisCourt` has 4 DPs of type `Player`: Player1, Player2, Player3, Player4.

Each `TennisPlayer` instance has its Player dependency property bound to one of the Player1..4 dependency properties of the containing `CourtControl`.

My ViewModel has several objects of type Player, and of course implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Whenever any of the players gets updated, `OnPropertyChanged` gets called.

My problem now is: when I create the player objects in my VM, `OnPropertyChanged` gets called, and it travels throughout: `VM -> TennisCourt.PlayerX -> TennisPlayer.Player`. This works fine the first time I call it. However, the player photos are being obtained asynchronously, and after that operation finishes, the `OnPropertyChanged` for each player object in VM is called again.

Now, after doing some tests I noticed, that the first control in the line (`TennisCourt`) does receive the `PropertyChanged` notification, and it obtains the object from VM again. However, since the Player object did not actually change (the reference is to the same object, it's just a field in the object that changed), the `TennisCourt.PlayerX` property does not seem to be raising its built in `OnPropertyChanged` event, so the binding `TennisCourt.PlayerX -> TennisPlayer.Player` does not have any effect, and the `TennisPlayer.Player` field doesn't get updated. If I decide to actually change the Player object in VM it does update, but that's not what I want to do.

Am I doing anything wrong? Is such cascade binding not a good practice? At first my `TennisCourt` did not have any DPs, and each `TennisPlayer.Player` was bound directly to a VM.Player. This worked perfectly well until I created a second instance of `TennisCourt` and wanted it to show different players.

Comment: pls post your xaml for the usercontrol bindings

Answer (score 1):

`DependancyProperty` is static so all instances of your court would get the same property.

Answer (score 0):

use simply properties with INotifyPropertyChanged and no dependency properties.